# UISwitch not returning its current state (on/off)

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

Here is the IBAction method linked to the UISwitch with the valueChanged event :

```
- (IBAction) sanitySwitch {
if (checkoption.on == YES) {
    NSLog(@"SanityCheck ENABLED");
    sanityCheck = YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"SanityCheck DISABLED");
    sanityCheck = NO;
}
}
```

It always returns "SanityCheck DISABLED". The UISwitch checkoption is correcty linked to its object from the XIB file and proper @propery and @syntetize setting have been placed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace the code with the this code.
and connect again with switch as value change control event.

```
- (IBAction) sanitySwitch:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"SanityCheck ENABLED");
        sanityCheck = YES;
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"SanityCheck DISABLED");
        sanityCheck = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: To markup code indent by 4 spaces or select the code and press the `010` button - no need for html tag etc.

Comment: I had a totally weird problem where YOU DO HAVE TO USE "sender", rather than self.yourSwitch, for "isOn" (or .on) to work.  Who knows?

Answer (score -1):

You are using property "on" wrong way
You have to check as follows:

```
if ([checkoption isOn])
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006784-CH3-SW5) properly.

Comment: I've tried to use if ([checkoption isOn]), the method still always returns "SanityCheck DISABLED".

Comment: Satyam, `getter=foo` only applies to explicit calls like `[switch isOn]`, not to the dot-syntax.